# How do I write a DAX Query in Power BI that compares text values to determine if a change has occurred?

Tags: powerbi, dax

Essentially, we have a list of departments and risk ratings by year. Ideally, for cases where a department has increased in risk between 2021 and 2022, the result would be "Increase," where risk has stayed the same it would be "No Change," and where it's decreased it would be "Decrease." We only care about 2022 being compared to 2021. How would you write this query? Here's a sample with dummy data:

| Dep | Year | Risk Rating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2022 | Low |
| A | 2021 | Low |
| A | 2020 | Low |
| B | 2022 | High |
| B | 2021 | Low |
| B | 2020 | Low |
| C | 2022 | Low |
| C | 2021 | High |
| C | 2020 | High |
| D | 2022 | Medium |
| D | 2021 | Medium |
| D | 2020 | Medium |

Thanks so much for any help you can provide.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a table expression to create a new table with only `Year` = 2022 and a `SWITCH` to return Increase or Decrease base on the values of `Risk Rating` in 2021 et 2022.

I've kept the column "RiskRating21" but you can delete it.

```
`EVALUATE
ADDCOLUMNS(
    FILTER(
        Data,
        Data[Year] = 2022
    ),
    "RiskRating21",
    CALCULATE(
        MAX(Data[Risk Rating]),
        Data[Dep] = EARLIER(Data[Dep]),
        Data[Year] = 2021
    ),
    "Var",
    VAR rr21 =
    CALCULATE(
        MAX(Data[Risk Rating]),
        Data[Dep] = EARLIER(Data[Dep]),
        Data[Year] = 2021
    )
    VAR rr22 =
    Data[Risk Rating]
    RETURN
    SWITCH(
        TRUE(),
        rr21 = "Low" &&
        rr22 IN {"Medium", "High"},
        "Increase",
        rr21 = "Medium" &&
        rr22 = "High",
        "Increase",
        rr21 <> rr22 && NOT ISBLANK(rr21),
        "Decrease",
        BLANK()
    )
        
)
```